# How to include outside parameter into List

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am getting the shopping cart quantity separately from a different class as shown below.I want to reduce that shopping cart quantity from the Quantity that contains in the List.So how can I include that in my query. Anyone please suggest me.

```
//int quantityinshoppingcart = classes.ShoppingCart.checkingQuantity(CustomerId,ItemId);


//Binds the data to the repeater control
rptcontrol.DataSource =   from p in l_List
      select new
      {
        ItemId = p.ItemId,
        ItemName = p.ItemName,
        Quantity = p.Quantity,                                                        
        //I want quantity as (Quantity = p.quantity - quantityinshoppingcart),
      };
      rptcontrol.DataBind();
```

Comment: _"//I want quantity as (Quantity = p.quantity - quantityinshoppingcart)"_ So did it work?

Comment: what error are you getting?didn't above code work?

Comment: It should work without any problem, what is the error you get?

Answer (score 5):

you can use the `let` keyword in your query :

```
var q = from p in l_List
        let quantityInShoppingCart = MethodThatGetsThisQuantity(p.ItemId)
        let computedQuantity = p.Quantity - quantityInShoppingCart
        select new { ItemId = p.ItemId,
                     ItemName = p.ItemName,
                     Quantity = computedQuantity 
                   };
```

Comment: Previous comment withdrawn after your edit, this looks good to me now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, it will be ok if l_List is fully loaded (i.e. may not work if it tries to run a query at the point of accessing the datasource).

```
//Binds the data to the repeater control
rptcontrol.DataSource =   from p in l_List
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            ItemId = p.ItemId,
                                            ItemName = p.ItemName,
                                            Quantity = p.Quantity - SampleProject._classes.ShoppingCart.checkingQuantity(CustomerId,p.ItemId)                                                
                                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried  to include your quantityinshoppingcart computation in you Linq Expression ?
Like this ?

```
rptcontrol.DataSource =   from p in l_List
      select new
      {
        ItemId = p.ItemId,
        ItemName = p.ItemName,
        Quantity = p.Quantity - SampleProject._classes.ShoppingCart.checkingQuantity(CustomerId, p.ItemId),                                                        
        //I want quantity as (Quantity = p.quantity - quantityinshoppingcart),
      };
      rptcontrol.DataBind();
```

Depending on the relative sizes of the shopping cart and l_List, and the cost of accessing the shopping cart content, you might want to use a pre-built Dictionary  during binding to quickly access the quantities in the shopping cart.

Hope this will help